# Scraping data from an internal SSL site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.6

I am attempting to scrape data from an internal company issue ticketing site.  For ex: https://servicetickets.company.corp/issue/xxxxx where the last 5 characters signify the ticket number.

The site is only accessible via the company network. I can access each ticket individually, but not through a scraping script. It looks like scraping anything is blocked on the company network. We do have an open network with which I am able to scrape other open sites, but not the ticketing site.

I am currently using Beautiful Soup and requests like so, and have tried the following:

```
scrapegoat = requests.get('https://servicetickets.company.corp/issue/xxxxx')
```

Error on open network: 
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='support.abc.xyz.corp', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /abc/support/message/17xxxxxx3 (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))

Error on internal network: SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='support.abc.xyz.corp', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /abc/support/message/17xxxxx53 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

Then, tried this on the internal network:

```
 scrapegoat = requests.get('https://servicetickets.company.corp/issue/xxxxx', verify=False)
```

But this returns a < Response [403] >

Next, I tried exporting the single sign on certificate from Apple Keychain as described [here](https://www.comodo.com/support/products/authentication_certs/setup/mac_chrome.php), but in step 8, it throws an error, being unable to export the certificate.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ0hF.png)

I was able to export the another certificate from keychain (Built-in Certificate authority), I have also tried installing and adding the certifi/cacert.pem to the verify path.

```
 scrapegoat = requests.get('https://servicetickets.company.corp/issue/xxxxx', verify='/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem')
```

These too lead to an SSL Error.

Has anyone faced a similar problem and successfully found a work around? Suggestions welcome too.

Comment: did you try it without SSL, i.e. `http://....` ? Good luck.

Comment: I am betting that you have a PKI certificate stored in your browser that is being passed to the server when a request is made.  If this is the case, you might be able to export it, decrypt it, and pass it as part of the `get` request.

Comment: @shellter Yes, it's only accessible via https.